# Is it possible to create a variable, that doesn't change on refresh the page, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, partial-page-refresh

After I ask this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218070/reload-contents-of-div-using-javascript):

I was thinking about this solution:

- Create a boolean flag inside the *javascript* script and make it *true*:

  - ***true*** indicates refreshing the page using the browser.
  - ***false*** indicates refreshing the page using a button.
- Inside *onclick* attribute of the button, I set *flag* to *false* and call `window.location.reload()` to refresh the page.
- Inside *onload* attribute of *`<body>`* tag, I check the *flag* if it's true switch to `Home` tab else switch to `Page1` tab where it contains the *`<div>`* tag I want to refresh its contents. After that, set *flag* to *true*.*

But unfortunately it doesn't work and *`flag`* is always *true* when it comes to *onload* attribute of *`<body>`* tag. Is it possible (somehow) to create a variable, that doesn't change on refresh the page, in javascript?

*<sub>My page consistes of many tabs, first one is Home (where it should be shown when refreshing the page using the browser) and second one is Page1 (where it contains the *`<div>`* tag I want to refresh its contents and where it should be shown when refreshing the page using the button)</sub>

Comment: this sounds like a perfect cookie situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is stateless, which means that everything on the page is refreshed each time the page loads.

There are a few ways to store persistant information that you can access between requests:

- Store the data you want in a cookie and read it when the page loads
- Pass data to the URL and read the current URL (including the data that you passed) when the page loads. For example: Redirect the browser to http://something.com/yourpage.html#flag=true if the user refreshed through the browser or redirect to http://something.com/yourpage.html#flag=false if the user clicked the button. On the onload of the page just read the current URL and see what the flag is.
- Use a cookie to create a session and store data on the server (technically this is very similar to the first option except you just store a token on the client and pass it to the server to retrieve data that was stored there)

Answer (score 3):

No. However, you can store the variable's value in a number of ways.

- a cookie
- in the url (query string)
- hidden element on page set from a session variable.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a situation where you could use sessionStorage or localStorage in the browser and if the browser doesn't support that, you could fallback on cookies...

Answer (score 1):

You can persist the data by using cookies, window.name, and window.location.hash key